# Pull Event Created Time from PowerShell - Server 2003

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to pull the event time using this power shell 1 script on a Windows 2003 Server.

What is the proper syntax?

```
$actions = (Get-EventLog -LogName "Application" -Message "*Succeeded*" -After (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-80))

if ($actions){
    ForEach($action in $actions){
        $Result = "Done - Job COMPLETED OK at ***** EVENT TIME HERE *****"
        Write-Host $Result
        Exit 0
    }
```

Comment: Change `"Done - Job COMPLETED OK at ***** EVENT TIME HERE *****"` to `"Done - Job COMPLETED OK at $($action.TimeGenerated)"`

Comment: AH - Thanks! Now its fine!